# retrieve values from arraylist of hashmap in java?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I've a hashmap as shown below.

```
indexMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

I could collect values from string like this,

```
        String[] keysProblem2 = (String[]) indexMap.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
```

How to collect values from arraylist? I tried doing like this,

```
        Integer [] valuesProblem2 =  (Integer[]) indexMap.values().toArray(new Integer[indexMap.size()]);
```

but was given an error like this,

```
 java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.String
at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Are you trying to collect *all* Integer values in each ArrayList in the HashMap, or are you just trying to collect the Integer values pertaining to one individual key?

Comment: @vulcan I want to collect all integer values of arraylist in Hashmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexMap.values()` returns a `Collection` of `ArrayList<Integer>`s. You can't call `.toArray(new Integer[indexMap.size()])` because it's a collection of `ArrayList<Integer>`, not `Integer`s.

If you want to iterate through all ArrayLists, and create one large `Integer[]`, then you'd have to do something like this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrays = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(indexMap.values());
ArrayList<Integer> allInts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(ArrayList<Integer> ints : arrays) {
   allInts.addAll(ints);
}
Integer[] valuesProblem2 = (Integer[])allInts.toArray(new Integer[0]);
```